# Is there a better way of designing zend_forms rather than using decorators?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-decorators

I am currently using zend_decorators to add styles to my form. I was wondering if there is an alternative way of doing it? It is a bit difficult to write decorators. I would love the casual one using divs and css style :

```
<input type="submit" class="colorfulButton" >
```

It is much simpler rather than set a decorator for a certain control and add it. Since it requires creating a decorator for each style implementation and adding it up with the control. Will view helpers to the trick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few ways. You can roll your own element view helpers (which could get rather clumsy soon I guess).

Or... you could use a viewscript for the form, like this (very basic example):

```
class Your_Form extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setDecorators( array(
            'PrepareElements',
             array( 'ViewScript', array( 'viewScript' => 'path/to/viewscript.phtml' ) )
        ) );

        // only use basic decorators for elements
        $decorators = array(
            'ViewHelper',
            'Label',
            'Errors'
        );

        // create some element
        $someElement = new Zend_Form_Element_Text( 'someElement' );
        // set the basic decorators for this element and set a css class
        $someElement->setDecorators( $decorators )
                    ->setAttrib( 'class', 'someCssClass' );

        // add (potentially multiple) elements to this from
        $this->addElements( array(
            $someElement
        ) );

    }
}
```

See the [standard decorators section about PrepareElements](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardDecorators.html#zend.form.standardDecorators.prepareElements) for why it's needed to have the PrepareElements decorator set for the form, when using the ViewScript decorator.

Then in the viewscript:

```
<?
    // the form is available to the viewscript as $this->element
    $form = $this->element;
?>
<!-- put whatever html you like in this script and render the basic element decorators seperately -->
<div>
   <? if( $form->someElement->hasErrors() ): ?>
   <?= $form->someElement->renderErrors() ?>
   <? endif; ?>
   <?= $form->someElement->renderLabel(); ?>
   <?= $form->someElement->renderViewHelper(); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to set a class attribute on a form element, there is no need to define a decorator : this can be done using some standard methods of zend_form's elements.

See the **`setAttrib()`** method, in the section [**Metadata and Attributes**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.elements.html#zend.form.elements.metadata) of the manual, and the example that's given there *(quoting)* :

```
// Equivalent to $element->setAttrib('class', 'text'):
$element->class = 'text;
```

And if you can set a class attribute this way, you can probably set it while constructing your form's elements, or in a .ini file that would define those elements -- there is an example that shows that a bit later in the page, in the [**Configuration**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.elements.html#zend.form.elements.config) section.

Comment: I agree with this answer for simple cases. But what if we have some sort of design complexity? Like having layered div with different form element per layer and the likes.

Comment: In this (complex) case, I suppose you'll have to use decorators, yes.