# Zend Form Decorators for special table

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

how can i get this table from my ZEND_FORM?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>label 1</th>
        <th>label 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>form element 1</td>
        <td>form element 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is what I have. But this is not correct.

```
$kinder_decorators = array(
        'ViewHelper', 
        'Errors',

        array('Label', array('tag' => 'th')),
        array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td'))


    );
```

Can anybody help please?

BR Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use a [ViewScript decorator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardDecorators.html#zend.form.standardDecorators.viewScript) on the whole form I'm afraid. The ViewScript decorator offers more flexibility for more complex layouts of form elements.

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619593/is-there-a-better-way-of-designing-zend-forms-rather-than-using-decorators/2634620#2634620) for a small example. If it's unclear, hit me up with a comment, and I'll expand a little on it here.

Comment: if its possible, can u explain it a little bit, regarding to what i need? tia

Comment: @frgtv10: what part of the example do you have trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this type of structure . Since its not possible to wrap two different labels inside same row and two different form element inside another row . Your markup is incorrect btw you should be doing

```
<tr><td>label1</td><td>form element 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>label2</td><td>form element 2</td></tr>

$kinder_decorators = array(
        'ViewHelper', 
        'Errors',
array(array('content' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td'))
array('Label', array('tag' => 'th')),
array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'tr'))


    );
```

Comment: His table markup is fine (if that was what you were referring to).

Comment: see the problem is when using decorate label and form element together become one entity hence they cannot be separated as in his posted markup.

Comment: I agree there, but that doesn't make his table markup incorrect of course; just not easily reproducible with form element decorators (if at all, indeed).